# A "soft" caress

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a verse of the song *Stay up* by George Nozuka.

> Let me start with a soft caress
>   Wanna show you I'm not like the rest
>   So put me to the test
>   Anything that you feel let it go
>   Wanna take things nice and slow
>   So baby lose control
>   I want this, more than
>   I want anything, anything

In the first line, what does *soft* mean when it's used to describe a caress, does it mean gentle? From what I've looked up, there are several definitions that seems applicable to the context, however, its example provided describes something else. For example, Dictionary.com sense #4 defines *soft* as
"producing agreeable sensations; pleasant or comfortable", but its example given is *soft slumber.* Sense #8 defines *soft* as "gentle or mild" but its example is *soft breezes.* So what does *soft* mean used in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not discriminate between the two senses; in this case they overlap. (Indeed most such definitions overlap: new senses arise out of old ones because the old sense is pushed a little bit this way or a little bit that way to meet new circumstances.)

Aware that he is being *"put to the test"*, the singer is anxious to show that he is *"not like the rest"*, that he is as concerned for his partner's gratification as his own. So he starts (*"wanna take things nice and slow"*) with a *"soft caress"*, one which is **"gentle"**, not harsh or demanding  in order to **"produce agreeable sensations"** (*"that you feel"*), which will induce her to lower her defenses, to *"let it go"* and *"lose control"*.